# Fiction novel/short involving dinosaurs who fed off radiation, involving dropping nuke on them

Tags: story-identification, books, dinosaurs

I'm searching for a novel, or maybe it was a short story. I read it before the year 2000. It was in Russian, but I suppose it was translated from English. Can't recall any of the names though.

The plot, in parts I can recall, was:

- people find either a dinosaur egg, or baby dinosaur, or a similar large reptile-like;
- these dinosaurs or whatever walk around Earth feeding off radiation. They actually eat radioactive stuff and leave no radiation behind; I recall at one point one of the human characters says something along the lines of "looks like we have our nuclear waste problem solved";
- people try to kill these dinosaurs but fail; and at one point there is a plan to drop a nuke on them. And at this point I had to stop reading and leave.

Comment: If the dinosaurs were singular rather than plural, I'd wonder if this wasn't some sort of *Godzilla* novelization. And, I wouldn't be overly concerned with a plot to take me out that involved sending me a lot of pizzas - trying to nuke something that eats radiation sounds like an obviously bad plan.

Comment: Nope, I recall at least two of these

Comment: They had wings to use as solar panels and the nuke scene was in the end of the book. Now need to find the book )

Answer (score 3):

[Kali Yuga](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=uk&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Ffantlab.ru%2Fwork12354) (russian "Калиюга", also "Милосердие динозавра") by Vasily Golovachev

> ...The paleontologist, ... followed him, but halfway to the ascent from
> the pit he returned and once again looked inside the monstrous egg -
> now it was quite obvious that it was an egg with a living embryo...

> ..."They must be left alive at least so that they cleanse the Earth of
> radiation."...

> ...Restell received official permission from the president to use the
> atomic bomb to destroy the monsters...

[Full text (russian)](https://www.rulit.me/books/kaliyuga-read-49759-1.html)

[image]